# MySQL Query a Query and return a COUNT based on a WHERE statement for both the first Query and the COUNT

Tags: mysql

Have to tables.
HOSTS and GUESTS.

HOST table looks like this.

```
* hid (INT, Primary Key, Auto-Increment)
* firstname (VARCHAR)
* lastname (VARCHAR)
* email (VARCHAR)
* registered (DATETIME)
* confirmed (DATETIME)
```

The **GUESTS** table looks like this:

```
* gid (INT, Primary Key, Auto-Increment)
* hid (INT)
* firstname (VARCHAR)
* lastname (VARCHAR)
* email (VARCHAR)
* registered (DATETIME)
* confirmed (DATETIME)
```

The desired outcome is to have output of rows with the HOSTS and the **COUNT** of how many GUESTS they have WHERE the **CONFIRMED** date and time is **before** 2013-11-10 14:00:00 for **both** the HOSTS and the GUESTS.

Have received an answer before but without the **WHERE** statement and that look like this:

```
SELECT   HOSTS.*, COUNT(gid)
FROM     HOSTS LEFT JOIN GUESTS USING (hid)
GROUP BY hid
```

How should the query look like to include the **before** 2013-11-10 14:00:00 for both the HOSTS and GUESTS?

Comment: Have you tried to include the WHERE-statement?

Comment: @PetervanderWal I came to add the WHERE-statement **before** GROUP BY. Like `WHERE confirmed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND confirmed < '2013-11-10 14:00:00'` but that seems only to affect the HOSTS.

Comment: Ok, almost there then. You can specify the table using HOSTS.confirmed < '2013-11-10 14:00:00' AND GUESTS.confirmed < '2013-11-10 14:00:00'

Comment: @PetervanderWal Ok. This is what I came up with: `SELECT firstname, lastname, email, COUNT(gid) FROM HOSTS LEFT JOIN GUESTS USING (bid) WHERE HOSTS.confirmeddatetime != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND HOSTS.confirmeddatetime < '2013-11-10 14:00:00' AND GUESTS.confirmed != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' AND GUESTS.confirmed < '2013-11-10 14:00:00' GROUP BY HOSTS.bid ORDER BY gid DESC` But it seems not to give a correct answer. :)

Comment: Perhaps some sample data would help to demonstrate why the answer is not correct?

Answer (score 0):

use the below conditions, I am not sure of MYSQL exact syntax but try in this way, This is in DB2 , you may be required to change the WHERE condition in Subquery

```
SELECT *H.*, J.CNT_GID
FROM HOSTS AS H
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT G.HID, COUNT(GID) AS CNT_GID
FROM GUESTS AS G
WHERE GUESTS.CONFIRMED < DATE('2013-11-10 14:00:00') #you may need to change here
GROUP BY G.HID
) AS J
ON H.HID = J.HID
```